# A lot of undefined reference errors using opencv static-libraries in eclipse c++ linux

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, opencv, static-libraries

I am working in a c++ project using opencv libraries. I need them static, so after download them I built my program, but the output was a large number of undefined references. A part of it is the next lines:

```
   opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL35OPENCL_FN_clCreateImage3D_switch_fnP11_cl_contextmPK16_cl_image_formatmmmmmPvPi+0x58): undefined reference to `dlsym'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL35OPENCL_FN_clCreateImage3D_switch_fnP11_cl_contextmPK16_cl_image_formatmmmmmPvPi+0x1a5): undefined reference to `dlopen'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL35OPENCL_FN_clCreateImage3D_switch_fnP11_cl_contextmPK16_cl_image_formatmmmmmPvPi+0x1c0): undefined reference to `dlsym'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL35OPENCL_FN_clCreateImage3D_switch_fnP11_cl_contextmPK16_cl_image_formatmmmmmPvPi+0x21f): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(opencl_core.cpp.o): In function `OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueMapBuffer_switch_fn(_cl_command_queue*, _cl_mem*, unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned int, _cl_event* const*, _cl_event**, int*)':
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL38OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueMapBuffer_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memjmmmjPKP9_cl_eventPS4_Pi+0x60): undefined reference to `dlsym'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL38OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueMapBuffer_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memjmmmjPKP9_cl_eventPS4_Pi+0x1a5): undefined reference to `dlopen'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL38OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueMapBuffer_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memjmmmjPKP9_cl_eventPS4_Pi+0x1c0): undefined reference to `dlsym'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL38OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueMapBuffer_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memjmmmjPKP9_cl_eventPS4_Pi+0x21f): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(opencl_core.cpp.o): In function `OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueNativeKernel_switch_fn(_cl_command_queue*, void (*)(void*), void*, unsigned long, unsigned int, _cl_mem* const*, void const**, unsigned int, _cl_event* const*, _cl_event**)':
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL41OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueNativeKernel_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queuePFvPvES1_mjPKP7_cl_memPPKvjPKP9_cl_eventPSC_+0x61): undefined reference to `dlsym'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL41OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueNativeKernel_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queuePFvPvES1_mjPKP7_cl_memPPKvjPKP9_cl_eventPSC_+0x1a5): undefined reference to `dlopen'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL41OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueNativeKernel_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queuePFvPvES1_mjPKP7_cl_memPPKvjPKP9_cl_eventPSC_+0x1c0): undefined reference to `dlsym'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL41OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueNativeKernel_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queuePFvPvES1_mjPKP7_cl_memPPKvjPKP9_cl_eventPSC_+0x21f): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(opencl_core.cpp.o): In function `OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueWriteImage_switch_fn(_cl_command_queue*, _cl_mem*, unsigned int, unsigned long const*, unsigned long const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, void const*, unsigned int, _cl_event* const*, _cl_event**)':
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL39OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueWriteImage_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memjPKmS4_mmPKvjPKP9_cl_eventPS8_+0x60): undefined reference to `dlsym'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL39OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueWriteImage_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memjPKmS4_mmPKvjPKP9_cl_eventPS8_+0x1b5): undefined reference to `dlopen'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL39OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueWriteImage_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memjPKmS4_mmPKvjPKP9_cl_eventPS8_+0x1d0): undefined reference to `dlsym'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL39OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueWriteImage_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memjPKmS4_mmPKvjPKP9_cl_eventPS8_+0x22f): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(opencl_core.cpp.o): In function `OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueReadImage_switch_fn(_cl_command_queue*, _cl_mem*, unsigned int, unsigned long const*, unsigned long const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, void*, unsigned int, _cl_event* const*, _cl_event**)':
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL38OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueReadImage_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memjPKmS4_mmPvjPKP9_cl_eventPS7_+0x60): undefined reference to `dlsym'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL38OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueReadImage_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memjPKmS4_mmPvjPKP9_cl_eventPS7_+0x1b5): undefined reference to `dlopen'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL38OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueReadImage_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memjPKmS4_mmPvjPKP9_cl_eventPS7_+0x1d0): undefined reference to `dlsym'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL38OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueReadImage_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memjPKmS4_mmPvjPKP9_cl_eventPS7_+0x22f): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(opencl_core.cpp.o): In function `OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueMapImage_switch_fn(_cl_command_queue*, _cl_mem*, unsigned int, unsigned long, unsigned long const*, unsigned long const*, unsigned long*, unsigned long*, unsigned int, _cl_event* const*, _cl_event**, int*)':
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL37OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueMapImage_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memjmPKmS4_PmS5_jPKP9_cl_eventPS7_Pi+0x74): undefined reference to `dlsym'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL37OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueMapImage_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memjmPKmS4_PmS5_jPKP9_cl_eventPS7_Pi+0x1c5): undefined reference to `dlopen'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL37OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueMapImage_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memjmPKmS4_PmS5_jPKP9_cl_eventPS7_Pi+0x1e0): undefined reference to `dlsym'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL37OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueMapImage_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memjmPKmS4_PmS5_jPKP9_cl_eventPS7_Pi+0x23f): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(opencl_core.cpp.o): In function `OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueCopyBufferRect_switch_fn(_cl_command_queue*, _cl_mem*, _cl_mem*, unsigned long const*, unsigned long const*, unsigned long const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned int, _cl_event* const*, _cl_event**)':
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL43OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueCopyBufferRect_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memS2_PKmS4_S4_mmmmjPKP9_cl_eventPS6_+0x5c): undefined reference to `dlsym'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL43OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueCopyBufferRect_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memS2_PKmS4_S4_mmmmjPKP9_cl_eventPS6_+0x1c5): undefined reference to `dlopen'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL43OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueCopyBufferRect_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memS2_PKmS4_S4_mmmmjPKP9_cl_eventPS6_+0x1e0): undefined reference to `dlsym'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL43OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueCopyBufferRect_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memS2_PKmS4_S4_mmmmjPKP9_cl_eventPS6_+0x23f): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(opencl_core.cpp.o): In function `OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueReadBufferRect_switch_fn(_cl_command_queue*, _cl_mem*, unsigned int, unsigned long const*, unsigned long const*, unsigned long const*, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, unsigned long, void*, unsigned int, _cl_event* const*, _cl_event**)':
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL43OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueReadBufferRect_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memjPKmS4_S4_mmmmPvjPKP9_cl_eventPS7_+0x64): undefined reference to `dlsym'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL43OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueReadBufferRect_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memjPKmS4_S4_mmmmPvjPKP9_cl_eventPS7_+0x1cd): undefined reference to `dlopen'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL43OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueReadBufferRect_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memjPKmS4_S4_mmmmPvjPKP9_cl_eventPS7_+0x1e8): undefined reference to `dlsym'
opencl_core.cpp:(.text._ZL43OPENCL_FN_clEnqueueReadBufferRect_switch_fnP17_cl_command_queueP7_cl_memjPKmS4_S4_mmmmPvjPKP9_cl_eventPS7_+0x24f): undefined reference to `dlopen'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(matrix.cpp.o): In function `reduceMinC32f(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&)':
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZL13reduceMinC32fRKN2cv3MatERS0_+0x398): undefined reference to `ippicviMin_32f_C1R'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(matrix.cpp.o): In function `reduceMinC16s(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&)':
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZL13reduceMinC16sRKN2cv3MatERS0_+0x441): undefined reference to `ippicviMin_16s_C1R'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(matrix.cpp.o): In function `reduceMinC16u(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&)':
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZL13reduceMinC16uRKN2cv3MatERS0_+0x441): undefined reference to `ippicviMin_16u_C1R'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(matrix.cpp.o): In function `reduceMinC8u(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&)':
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZL12reduceMinC8uRKN2cv3MatERS0_+0x5de): undefined reference to `ippicviMin_8u_C1R'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(matrix.cpp.o): In function `reduceMaxC32f(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&)':
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZL13reduceMaxC32fRKN2cv3MatERS0_+0x398): undefined reference to `ippicviMax_32f_C1R'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(matrix.cpp.o): In function `reduceMaxC16s(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&)':
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZL13reduceMaxC16sRKN2cv3MatERS0_+0x441): undefined reference to `ippicviMax_16s_C1R'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(matrix.cpp.o): In function `reduceMaxC16u(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&)':
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZL13reduceMaxC16uRKN2cv3MatERS0_+0x441): undefined reference to `ippicviMax_16u_C1R'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(matrix.cpp.o): In function `reduceMaxC8u(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&)':
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZL12reduceMaxC8uRKN2cv3MatERS0_+0x5de): undefined reference to `ippicviMax_8u_C1R'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(matrix.cpp.o): In function `reduceSumC_8u16u16s32f_64f(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&)':
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZL26reduceSumC_8u16u16s32f_64fRKN2cv3MatERS0_+0x16b): undefined reference to `ippicviSum_32f_C4R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZL26reduceSumC_8u16u16s32f_64fRKN2cv3MatERS0_+0x213): undefined reference to `ippicviSum_8u_C1R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZL26reduceSumC_8u16u16s32f_64fRKN2cv3MatERS0_+0x293): undefined reference to `ippicviSum_8u_C3R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZL26reduceSumC_8u16u16s32f_64fRKN2cv3MatERS0_+0x29f): undefined reference to `ippicviSum_8u_C4R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZL26reduceSumC_8u16u16s32f_64fRKN2cv3MatERS0_+0x2ab): undefined reference to `ippicviSum_16u_C1R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZL26reduceSumC_8u16u16s32f_64fRKN2cv3MatERS0_+0x2b7): undefined reference to `ippicviSum_16u_C3R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZL26reduceSumC_8u16u16s32f_64fRKN2cv3MatERS0_+0x2c3): undefined reference to `ippicviSum_16u_C4R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZL26reduceSumC_8u16u16s32f_64fRKN2cv3MatERS0_+0x2cf): undefined reference to `ippicviSum_16s_C1R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZL26reduceSumC_8u16u16s32f_64fRKN2cv3MatERS0_+0x2db): undefined reference to `ippicviSum_16s_C3R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZL26reduceSumC_8u16u16s32f_64fRKN2cv3MatERS0_+0x2e7): undefined reference to `ippicviSum_16s_C4R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZL26reduceSumC_8u16u16s32f_64fRKN2cv3MatERS0_+0x30b): undefined reference to `ippicviSum_32f_C3R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZL26reduceSumC_8u16u16s32f_64fRKN2cv3MatERS0_+0x317): undefined reference to `ippicviSum_32f_C1R'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(matrix.cpp.o): In function `cv::ipp_sort(cv::Mat const&, cv::Mat&, int)':
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cvL8ipp_sortERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xb0): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixDescend_64f_I'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cvL8ipp_sortERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xf4): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixGetBufferSize'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cvL8ipp_sortERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xa01): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixDescend_8u_I'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cvL8ipp_sortERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xa4d): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixGetBufferSize'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cvL8ipp_sortERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xb43): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixAscend_8u_I'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cvL8ipp_sortERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xc94): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixAscend_16s_I'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cvL8ipp_sortERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xd64): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixAscend_16u_I'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cvL8ipp_sortERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xd75): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixDescend_16s_I'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cvL8ipp_sortERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xd86): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixDescend_16u_I'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cvL8ipp_sortERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xda0): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixAscend_32s_I'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cvL8ipp_sortERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xdb1): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixDescend_32s_I'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cvL8ipp_sortERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xdc2): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixDescend_32f_I'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cvL8ipp_sortERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xddc): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixAscend_32f_I'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cvL8ipp_sortERKNS_3MatERS0_i+0xdfa): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixAscend_64f_I'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(matrix.cpp.o): In function `cv::sortIdx(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&, int)':
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv7sortIdxERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEi+0x853): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixIndexDescend_8u'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv7sortIdxERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEi+0x890): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixIndexGetBufferSize'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv7sortIdxERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEi+0x9fa): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixIndexDescend_32f'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv7sortIdxERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEi+0xbf4): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixIndexGetBufferSize'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv7sortIdxERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEi+0x1230): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixIndexAscend_8u'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv7sortIdxERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEi+0x1250): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixIndexAscend_32s'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv7sortIdxERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEi+0x129e): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixIndexAscend_16u'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv7sortIdxERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEi+0x1368): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixIndexAscend_16s'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv7sortIdxERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEi+0x1374): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixIndexDescend_32s'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv7sortIdxERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEi+0x1380): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixIndexDescend_16s'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv7sortIdxERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEi+0x138c): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixIndexDescend_16u'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv7sortIdxERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayEi+0x13ac): undefined reference to `ippicvsSortRadixIndexAscend_32f'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(matrix.cpp.o): In function `cv::transpose(cv::_InputArray const&, cv::_OutputArray const&)':
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xbd5): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32f_C4R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xc0b): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_8u_C1R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xd7f): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32f_C4IR'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xda6): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16u_C3R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xdb2): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16u_C1R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xdbe): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_8u_C4R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xdca): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_8u_C3R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xe86): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32f_C3IR'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xe92): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32f_C1IR'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xe9e): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32s_C4IR'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xeaa): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32s_C3IR'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xeb6): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32s_C1IR'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xec2): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16s_C4IR'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xece): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16s_C3IR'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xeda): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16s_C1IR'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xee6): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16u_C4IR'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xef2): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16u_C3IR'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xefe): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16u_C1IR'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xf0a): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_8u_C4IR'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xf16): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_8u_C3IR'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xf22): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_8u_C1IR'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xf6a): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16s_C4R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xf76): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16s_C3R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xf82): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16s_C1R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xf8e): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_16u_C4R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xf9a): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32f_C1R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xfa6): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32s_C4R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xfb2): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32s_C3R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0xfbe): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32s_C1R'
matrix.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv9transposeERKNS_11_InputArrayERKNS_12_OutputArrayE+0x1032): undefined reference to `ippicviTranspose_32f_C3R'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(arithm.cpp.o): In function `cv::hal::mul8u(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned char*, unsigned long, int, int, void*)':
arithm.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal5mul8uEPKhmS2_mPhmiiPv+0xf62): undefined reference to `ippicviMul_8u_C1RSfs'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(arithm.cpp.o): In function `cv::hal::mul16u(unsigned short const*, unsigned long, unsigned short const*, unsigned long, unsigned short*, unsigned long, int, int, void*)':
arithm.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal6mul16uEPKtmS2_mPtmiiPv+0xa58): undefined reference to `ippicviMul_16u_C1RSfs'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(arithm.cpp.o): In function `cv::hal::mul32f(float const*, unsigned long, float const*, unsigned long, float*, unsigned long, int, int, void*)':
arithm.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal6mul32fEPKfmS2_mPfmiiPv+0x799): undefined reference to `ippicviMul_32f_C1R'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(arithm.cpp.o): In function `cv::hal::cmp16s(short const*, unsigned long, short const*, unsigned long, unsigned char*, unsigned long, int, int, void*)':
arithm.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal6cmp16sEPKsmS2_mPhmiiPv+0x94): undefined reference to `ippicviCompare_16s_C1R'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(arithm.cpp.o): In function `cv::hal::cmp16u(unsigned short const*, unsigned long, unsigned short const*, unsigned long, unsigned char*, unsigned long, int, int, void*)':
arithm.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal6cmp16uEPKtmS2_mPhmiiPv+0x93): undefined reference to `ippicviCompare_16u_C1R'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(arithm.cpp.o): In function `cv::hal::cmp32f(float const*, unsigned long, float const*, unsigned long, unsigned char*, unsigned long, int, int, void*)':
arithm.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal6cmp32fEPKfmS2_mPhmiiPv+0x93): undefined reference to `ippicviCompare_32f_C1R'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(arithm.cpp.o): In function `cv::hal::cmp8u(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned char*, unsigned long, int, int, void*)':
arithm.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal5cmp8uEPKhmS2_mPhmiiPv+0x8d): undefined reference to `ippicviCompare_8u_C1R'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(arithm.cpp.o): In function `cv::hal::mul16s(short const*, unsigned long, short const*, unsigned long, short*, unsigned long, int, int, void*)':
arithm.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal6mul16sEPKsmS2_mPsmiiPv+0x627): undefined reference to `ippicviMul_16s_C1RSfs'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(arithm.cpp.o): In function `cv::hal::add8u(unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned char const*, unsigned long, unsigned char*, unsigned long, int, int, void*)':
arithm.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal5add8uEPKhmS2_mPhmiiPv+0x64): undefined reference to `ippicviAdd_8u_C1RSfs'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(arithm.cpp.o): In function `cv::hal::add16u(unsigned short const*, unsigned long, unsigned short const*, unsigned long, unsigned short*, unsigned long, int, int, void*)':
arithm.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal6add16uEPKtmS2_mPtmiiPv+0x65): undefined reference to `ippicviAdd_16u_C1RSfs'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(arithm.cpp.o): In function `cv::hal::add16s(short const*, unsigned long, short const*, unsigned long, short*, unsigned long, int, int, void*)':
arithm.cpp:(.text._ZN2cv3hal6add16sEPKsmS2_mPsmiiPv+0x65): undefined reference to `ippicviAdd_16s_C1RSfs'
/usr/local/lib/libopencv_core.a(arithm.cpp.o): In function `cv::hal::add32f(float const*, unsigned long, float const*, unsigned long, float*, unsigned long, int, int, void*)':
```

What I have modified in the properties of the project is in: Properties->C/C++Build->Settings->Linker->Libraries
in te -l gap all the libraries I need, and in the -L gap the path /usr/local/lib where I have already checked that the libraries exists in that path.

I have also modified in:
Properties->C/C++Build->Settings->Linker->Miscellaneous
I have wrote -static in linker flags gap.

Am I missing something? What should I do?

Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: I know this is an old one but I have the same kind of problem. Did you solved it ?

Answer (score 0):

You need to link executable with `libdl` using `-ldl` flag.